# Getting user input in ruby using atom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, atom-editor

I'm getting input for ruby in atom. Everything is OK and my code is running, not showing any error, but the issue is that it’s not getting input. I mean I can’t type in the output console. Kindly help me.

Here is the image where I can’t edit user input

[image: Atom Runner]

Comment: Can we see the code you are using?

Comment: Please paste the code you are using in the question.

Comment: "puts=("type your name:")
name=gets()
puts(name)"

------

Here is the code I'm using kindly guide me on this properly , and also guide me if there is any package needed there??

Comment: Please give me Any ans?

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this message doesn't come in too late.
But the answer to your question is :
**UNFORTUNATELY** Atom does not currently allow for providing input
what you can do is write the code in atom, and run it in terminal or command line
and you will be able to provide the input as required

**Summary:** you will have to write the code in atom and test it in terminal or CMD
alternatively you can develop in the terminal and this wont be an issue.

HAPPY CODING :)